# Why setState(hook) in function component cause an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(1)
  setA(2)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{a}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Error. Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Why it can cause an infinite loop?

I think the reason is that **function component** just as a **render function**, so it will cause infinite loop when `setState` in `render` functions.

Is there any official explanation?

Comment: if you update state - your component re-renders again and setA function called every time when component re-rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `setA` you actually update a state variable and trigger a re-render of you component.

When the component re-render it will call `setA` (just before the rendering) and will trigger a re-render again.

Can you see the infinite loop ?

Traditionally you update a state variable into a callback (i.e when the user click on a button) or under certains conditions.

In your example, you can directly set `a` to 2

```
function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(2)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{a}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to have the first render with `a = 1`, then immediatly have `a = 2`, you can use an effect which will be executed only once (because of the empty array for the second argument)

```
function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(2)
  useEffect(() => setA(2), [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{a}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why not `useEffect(() => setA(2), [a])`  to skip the effect rather than passing empty array?

Comment: it depends what behavior you are expecting, with `[a]` in the second parameters, you will reset `a` to `2` each time `a` is updated so `a` will basically not be allowed to have other value than `2` (it can be equal to an other value for a very short period and will immediatly take the value `2`). With `[]`, the effect will be applied only once, `a` can take another value for the next renders

Comment: Thank you, now I know what "HOOKS" means. It works like a bridge between functional component and react.

Comment: exactly, hooks enable you to interact with react's stuffs (like state, refs, lifecycle method) inside a functional component

Answer (score 5):

On each state update `React` will re-render the component and run all the function body, as the  `setA(2)` is not enclosed in any hook or function and is a part of the function/component body. `React` will execute this on each render cycle. This make an infinite loop.

On Component mount React will set the state and go for the component update as the state updated, again there is state update React will again re-render the component. This cycle will continue until react reaches  the re-render limit.

You could avoid this by wrap the state update in hook.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(1)
  useEffect(() => {
    setA(2)
  },[]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{a}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting a new value to the state with `setA(2)`, so each time the component is rendered the state receives a new value, forcing the component to render again

Answer (score 0):

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
return {
<Component data= {someData}
           selectCallback ={ (rows) => {
                        console.log(rows);
                        setRows(rows); // if set State going infinity loop
}}
...remainProps
/>
```

**Its giving infinity loop when trying to setState and if we didn't use the setRows then in console giving right answers means array of objec**

Help appreciated.

Comment: i check all  `useEffect`  no one affect `someData` to re render

Answer (score 0):

Because calling `setA(2)` causes the component to re-render.